# Gradle project not importing correctly android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, ubuntu-14.04

I was working on the gradle project on android studio . My Pc froze due to some issue & I had to hard restart my ubuntu system.

Since then I'm trying to open my project but the project is not getting imported correctly & is showing no classes/packages etc.

I tried re importing it but still the same problem.

[image]

The warning it says is Unliked Gradle project.

I think maybe some project settings have been corrupted.

Please help how can I fix this.

Thanks

EDIT

On import Gradle project the following pops up

[image]

After doing import Gradle project I'm still not able to run the app & have the below

[image]

Comment: did you see any error message? if yes, please post the error message.

Comment: @Eyadoos yes it says unliked gradle project & then on clicking on it says import project from gradle. Pls see my edit